# Exception: "Evol.CoevolutionaryECSuite cannot be cast to ec.coevolve.GroupedProblemForm"

Tags: java

I'm trying to test the example that ECJ, the evolutionary computation system in Java, in Eclipse, gives us on Cooperative Coevolution, more specifically the CoevolutionaryECSuite one, and without altering the code that it is available I am getting this class cast exception: "Evol.CoevolutionaryECSuite cannot be cast to ec.coevolve.GroupedProblemForm". I think I have all the files necessary. Did anyone ever try to test this problem and had this exact problem or have any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: You should wrap the code excerpts in backticks(``), also you should provide some example code and some links to the resources you are referring to.

Comment: @Thermatix I can put the link to the ECJ zip where you can find the code that I am talking about. i don´t know if it´s very pratical to insert the full code in here. After you download the ECJ, the code is in the following directory: ecj/src/main/ec/app/coevolve2.

Comment: The link to the ECJ zip is this: https://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/ecj/

Comment: Okay so just now I had an epiphany and discover what the problem was. The cause for this problem was a change that I made in the parameters file, more specifically, the location to the source code of the actual problem. Thanks anyway.